# JQuery click() triggers event in console but calls default from JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a submit button. On manually clicking it, AJAX kicks in and prevents the default submit action. I want to trigger that behavior via JS or jQuery.

I have tried several methods:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(clicksubmitbutton(), 2000);
});

function clicksubmitbutton(){
    //I tried these lines one at a time. :
    $('#basketButton').click();
    $('#basketButton')[0].click();
    $('#basketButton').trigger('click');
    $('#basketButton').triggerHandler('click');
}
```

The first 3 all worked fine from console (AJAX), but reloaded the page when called within js. What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't invoke your function, just pass it. Observe the following...

```
setTimeout(clicksubmitbutton(), 2000);
```

=>

```
setTimeout(clicksubmitbutton, 2000);
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ywu8vvrh/) - working demo

---

Also, `.click()` should work fine

Comment: Argh. So it´s one of those days one feels like banging his head on the table. Thanks

Comment: hehe no worries, we all have those days :) So did you get it all figured out?